# Finding a file in a directory based on time

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I have a directory called /home/mydir/test A file will be sent from some other team which lands in this directory. How to find the file is whether in that directory for more than 4 hours.

I tried the below code.

```
find . -cmin -240
```

I don't think this is working . It lists all the file in the folder. What i want is to get the file names of the files which are in this directory for more than 4 hours. How to get that?

Answer (score 2):

Need +240, instead of -240.

```
find . -cmin +240
```

You might want to add -type f so only shows filenames and not directory names

```
find . -cmin +240 -type f
```

Comment: yes it's working fine now but i have a doubt , is it possible to print just the file name ? it prints with './' before the file name

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -cmin +240 -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

That will execute `basename` on each file found and provide only the name of the file.